# Shortest Path Between two vertexes

Tags: shortest-path

I got a graph, and asks me to find the shortest path between two vertices. We have to visit all of the vertices, or if we reach the destination vertex without visiting all the other vertices is correct?
Thanks, and sorry for the incovenience.

This is the graph:
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BhK6.jpg)

And the question is: 
Apply the shortest path algorithm to find the shortest path from A to G.

Answer (score 0):

The usual strategy for the shortest path between two vertices in an unweighted graph is a [Breadth-First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) (BFS), which visits every node of distance 1 from the starting point, then every node of distance 2... until it finds the target vertex.

The premise is simple: by visiting every node of increasing distance from the starting point, the path to the ending point *must* be the shortest possible path, because otherwise you would have found it previously.  As a more concrete example: if the first path you find is distance 4, that must be the shortest path, because you've already checked all paths of distance 3 or less.

Thus, to find the shortest path between two vertices in an unweighted graph, you conduct a BFS until you find the target vertex, then backtrack to the starting vertex, tracking the nodes you traverse.  This is guaranteed to be the shortest path (or tied for the shortest path).

If the graph is weighted (you do not specify), then you must traverse every possible path to the target node, not just the one passing through the fewest vertices.

Comment: i've edited my question with the graph and the question(my bad at all). But i think i understood you.

Answer (score 0):

As a complenetary to Clayton L, in case the graph is weighted (yet with non-negative weights), you can use Dijkstra's algorithm. If it is weighted with negative weights yet doesn't contain a negative cycle, you can use Bellman-Ford. If it does contain a negative cycle, then you're out of luck, and you need to alter the weights in some sense, as a path can exploit the negative cycle and take the path's weight to any negative number.

Comment: In classes we've never talked about negative cycles, so i think thar Dijkstra's algorithm is the best one...